# Stargate Universe blunder: whey do they keep talking about Naquadria when it should be Naquada...?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

I can't be the only one to notice that in *Stargate Universe* they keep talking about Naquadria when it should be Naquada, because, as far as I'm aware, Naquadria only existed on Langara, Jonas Quinn's homeworld, after experiments done by a Goa'uld named Thanos. That's when we learn it's not naturally occurring anywhere in nature, yet in SGU we are on planets with a Naquadria core. Is this a major oversight on the writers part, forgetting their own lore? Because this is a huge mistake on their part, and it drives me mad every time I watch it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there a question here?  I'm looking for punctuation, and I'm not really finding any.  Please summarize your question in the title of your post (and it should be a _question_) and then explain it more fully in the body.  I don't normally bug people about punctuation, but please at least put a question mark in your post so you indicate what the question is.  You might want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: There's also the  Sha'uri/Sha're annoyance, Gould/Go'aould etc.. Lots to be annoyed about. Could you make it clearer what the actual question is?

Comment: With *Universe* being cut short, there may have been some intention to follow up on the naquadria core (perhaps someone other than their Thanos had done some experimenting, or this was what he did with the outcome?)

Comment: P4X-351 has a core made of Naquadria, the formation of which was the result of the planet being a former Goa'uld or Ancient testing ground.  There is no inconsistency.

Comment: @DoscoJones - There's also a planet in the Destiny galaxy that has a similar core. It's not apparent whether this is a naturally occurring process

Answer (score 18):

I think you've fundamentally misunderstood what's happening here. Langara has been tampered with by a Goa'uld in order to turn a seam of naquada into a seam of naquadria, using crystal technology similar to that employed by the Tok'Ra.

Jonas is convinced that naquadria can **only be found on his planet**...

> **JONAS:** *We found a reference to a process the Goa'uld discovered which allowed them to convert raw Naquada into Naquadria while it's still in the ground. Now somehow it started a change reaction which has continued on down through the veins getting deeper and deeper and deeper, and we believe that the process is ongoing.*
> ...
> *You know for the longest time I was wondering why we never found any naquadria anywhere else in the galaxy and now I'm thinking it's because it doesn't exist in nature at all.*

...**but he is, in fact, incorrect**. There are multiple planets in the universe with naquadria cores, including Dr. Rush's 'Icarus' planet ([P4X-351](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/P4X-351)), [another planet](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Icarus-like_planet) located by the Lucian Alliance (which comes complete with a pyramid, indicating that it possibly belonged to the same Goa'uld that was experimenting on Jonas' world) and a planet found in the galaxy that the Destiny is currently mapping.

> **KIVA:** *Similar naquadria deposits. We had some issues adapting the equations, but there should be enough power to get us there.*
>
> **RUSH:** *You've found another Icarus planet.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SGU: Subversion](https://www.gateworld.net/universe/s1/subversion/transcript/)</sup></sub>

And

> **RUSH:** *Yeah. We now have data on literally thousands of Gates that have already been seeded. Only managed to get through a fraction of it, but I found something quite interesting.*
>
> **WALLACE:** *Woah! Almost the same mineral composition as the Icarus planet.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SGU: Life](https://www.gateworld.net/universe/s1/life/transcript/)</sup></sub>